# Is there a way to get the full attribute name from a partial search, and save it as a variable?

Tags: xpath

I have

```
<div id="post_message_NUMBER">
                    Text 
</div>
```

which I find through an xpath search using `[id(contains, "post_message")]` and I would like to save `post_message_NUMBER` to make a second, more specific query using a variable or `%s` to fill it in, but I don't know what command to use to get the full name of the id, rather than some text or value from the document.

I was thinking to do something like `ID = #get the full id name` and then `Content = XS.xpath('[contains(@id, "%s")]//b//text()% ID)').getall()` where the start of the xpath is already saved as `XS`.

Would this work? I've never used `%s` before to any input there would be welcome.

Comment: here is the code for the first part `ID = response.xpath('//html//div[contains(@id, "post_message")]').xpath('@*').extract()`

Comment: I tried `XS = response.xpath('//html//div[contains(@id, "%s")]' % ID)` but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `Scrapy` and `Python 3`, this should work (I've corrected your XPath expressions and the declaration of the variable) :

```
id = response.xpath('//html//div[contains(@id, "post_message")]/@id').get()
xs = response.xpath('//html//div[contains(@id, "%s")]/text()'%str(id)).getall()
print(*xs, sep='\n')
```